# Groovy write to file (newline)

Tags: file-io, groovy

I created a small function that simply writes text to a file, but I am having issues making it write each piece of information to a new line. Can someone explain why it puts everything on the same line?

Here is my function:

```
public void writeToFile(def directory, def fileName, def extension, def infoList) {
    File file = new File("$directory/$fileName$extension")

    infoList.each {
        file << ("${it}\n")
    }
}
```

The simple code I'm testing it with is something like this:

```
def directory = 'C:/'
def folderName = 'testFolder'
def c

def txtFileInfo = []

String a = "Today is a new day"
String b = "Tomorrow is the future"
String d = "Yesterday is the past"

txtFileInfo << a
txtFileInfo << b
txtFileInfo << d

c = createFolder(directory, folderName) //this simply creates a folder to drop the txt file in

writeToFile(c, "garbage", ".txt", txtFileInfo)
```

The above creates a text file in that folder and the contents of the text file look like this:

```
Today is a new dayTomorrow is the futureYesterday is the past
```

As you can see, the text is all bunched together instead of separated on a new line per text. I assume it has something to do with how I am adding it into my list?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks to me, like you're working in windows in which case a new line character in not simply `\n` but rather `\r\n`

You can always get the correct new line character through  `System.getProperty("line.separator")` for example.

Comment: Hah that is correct, I can't believe I missed that (as I have dealt with it before). I may switch to the line.separator as that seems more universal. Thank you mfloryan

Comment: That's almost exactly what `java.io.PrintWriter` does to obtain the line separator string, so it's probably the best way to go.

Comment: Don't use this, take the `withWriter` solution from @steven and @tim-yates instead, much faster and also safer. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html for the API documentation. Also, `println` takes care by itself of the platform dependent line separator, no need to handle that manually.

Answer (score 88):

As @Steven points out, a better way would be:

```
public void writeToFile(def directory, def fileName, def extension, def infoList) {
  new File("$directory/$fileName$extension").withWriter { out ->
    infoList.each {
      out.println it
    }
  }
}
```

As this handles the line separator for you, and handles closing the writer as well

(and doesn't open and close the file each time you write a line, which could be slow in your original version)

Comment: @eskatos edit reverted, as the string matches that in the question (the `.` is being passed in `extension`)

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't see the dot in the question, sorry for the noise. Pretty weird tough :)

Comment: Not to mention that this code eschews the temporary variable, which probably makes this more efficient and definitely makes it more idiomatically Groovy :)

Comment: @inovaovao it depends if `infoList` is a `List` or a single string.  I'm guessing you just had a single String?

Comment: @tim_yates of course you are right. I removed my comment.

Comment: @inovaovao no worries :-)

Answer (score 10):

I came across this question and inspired by other contributors. I need to append some content to a file once per line. Here is what I did.

```
class Doh {
   def ln = System.getProperty('line.separator')
   File file //assume it's initialized 

   void append(String content) {
       file << "$content$ln"
   }
}
```

Pretty neat I think :)

Comment: Cool, but that will open the file, append to it, and then close it again each time. It would be quicker (depending on your use-case) to maintain a writer over the lifetime of Doh

Comment: true. should use file.withWriter instead.

Comment: And for reference, I've had to fix a ton of scripts that use this `file << "whatever"` syntax because they're painfully slow, more so if the output is over NFS. Like, in the extreme case I've seen scripts that went from 18 hours to half an hour just by fixing this.  One I fixed just now went from 4h20m to 5m.

Comment: Don't use this, take the `withWriter` solution from @steven and @tim-yates instead, much faster and also safer. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html for the API documentation. Also, `println` takes care by itself of the platform dependent line separator, no need to handle that manually.

Answer (score 8):

Might be cleaner to use `PrintWriter` and its method `println`.
Just make sure you close the writer when you're done

Comment: +1 You're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272330/groovy-write-to-file-newline/4275240#4275240

Answer (score 0):

@Comment for ID:14.
It's for me rather easier to write:

```
out.append it
```

instead of

```
out.println it
```

println did on my machine only write the first file of the ArrayList, with append I get the whole List written into the file.

Kindly anyway for the quick-and-dirty-solution.