# Gate : breakline after each loop in groovy

Tags: groovy, gate

i have this code that prints in the same line after each loop. For example:

"categorie=extragraphique","remarque=confusion_consonne","mot=article","categorie=logogrammique","remarque=aposthrophe","mot=conjonction"

i would like a linebreak after each loop but /n doesnt work and writeLine will do a different thing.

The wanted output is:
"categorie=extragraphique","remarque=confusion_consonne","mot=article"
"categorie=logogrammique","remarque=aposthrophe","mot=conjonction"

```
  new File("/outfile.txt").withWriterAppend{ out ->
  (doc.getNamedAnnotationSets() + [Default:(doc.getAnnotations())]).each{ setName, set ->
    set.each{ anno ->
      if( anno.getFeatures() )
        anno.getFeatures().each{ fValue ->
          out.write(/"${fValue}",/)
        }
      else
        out.write(/"${anno.getId()},,/)        
    }
  }
}
```

Thnaks in advance

Comment: It looks like a pure groovy question, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272330/groovy-write-to-file-newline

Comment: I don't understand the statement > _`/n` doesnt work and writeLine will do a different thing_ Can you explain it in more detail? The code looks like from a groovy expert, what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
  new File("/outfile.txt").withWriterAppend{ out ->
  (doc.getNamedAnnotationSets() + [Default:(doc.getAnnotations())]).each{ setName, set ->
    set.each{ anno ->
      if( anno.getFeatures() )
        anno.getFeatures().each{ fValue ->
          out.write(/"${fValue}",/)
        }
      else
        out.write(/"${anno.getId()},,/)        

      out.write('\n') //this line is new
    }
  }
}
```